# Java XSLT transformation

Tags: java, xslt

Using java, i transform HTML to XML. Does encoding type we mention in the XSL file play a role? Because after transformation, there is duplication of content in the XML file where in content gets append in the last and making the file invalid. Not able to replicate this issue again. This happens once in a while.

Comment: Simple test: Use `iso-8859-1` as encoding type, while the content contains non-ASCII characters.

Comment: Sounds more like a bug in the XSL template, but I don't think its related to the encoding.

Comment: First of all get a sample input. Duplication of content is most likely a parsing things twice by a bug in the rules. IF you cannot follow the logic (appy/match/call), place markers, some "XXX", "YYYY" in rules.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, the encoding of the xsl itself does not have any connection to the encoding of the source xml or the encoding of the target xml, unless there is a bug in the transformer.

Non the less the the xsl may print characters that are not printable in the target xml's encoding in which case your target xml would contain invalid characters (or the transformer throws an exception I'm not sure).

Finding a solution to your exact problem is rather impossible with this amount of information.